# Which Status Code for "client requested wrong format"?

Tags: http, http-status-codes, http-status-code-406

Which HTTP Status Code is the best to use for "Client requested a wrong format", e.g. the client requested `format=json` and the data is only available as XML? I tend to use 406 but this refers to the `Accept` heders, whereas the format is given as parameter in the query string in my usecase.

Is 406 the right code here anyway?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My advice is always to keep it simple.  Send a 400 Bad Request and in the response body add a message indicating why the request was bad (ie format json not available).

Answer (score 1):

No, if you don't have content for the request URI the most obvious choice is simply 404 (you can put details into the payload).